How to correctly modify the schema AST with this custom directive to expose a `query` field?
A while back I stumbled across this section of the Lighthouse-PHP documention, and I wanted to write a custom directive to automatically handle adding a query field to the return type of a field. However, I'm getting some perplexing errors when I actually try to use it.
Here is the directive in question:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\GraphQL\Directives;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\FieldDefinitionNode;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\InterfaceTypeDefinitionNode;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\NamedTypeNode;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\NameNode;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\NodeList;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\NonNullTypeNode;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\ObjectTypeDefinitionNode;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\StringValueNode;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\NonNull;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Exceptions\DefinitionException;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Execution\ResolveInfo;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\AST\DocumentAST;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Directives\BaseDirective;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\RootType;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Values\FieldValue;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\FieldManipulator;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\FieldMiddleware;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext;

/**
 * Wrap a mutation so that it returns a result type containing the regular
 * result, as well as a generic query field.
 *
 * For example, if you have a mutation like this:
 *
 * ```graphql
 * type Mutation {
 *     someMutation(input: SomeInputType!): SomeModel @field(resolver: "SomeResolver") @exposeQuery
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * That compiles down to:
 *
 * ```graphql
 * type Mutation {
 *     someMutation(input: SomeInputType!): SomeMutationResult!
 * }
 *
 * type SomeMutationResult {
 *     result: SomeModel
 *     query: Query!
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * @see https://lighthouse-php.com/6/the-basics/best-practices.html#in-the-mutation-response-return-a-field-of-type-query
 */
final class ExposeQueryDirective extends BaseDirective implements FieldManipulator, FieldMiddleware
{
    public static function definition(): string
    {
        return
            /** @lang GraphQL */
            <<<'GRAPHQL'
            """
            Wraps a mutation so that it returns a result type containing the regular
            result, as well as a generic query field that can be used to
            perform a mutation and query in a single request.
            """
            directive @exposeQuery(
                """
                The name to be given to the automatically-generated result type.
                """
                resultType: String
            ) on FIELD_DEFINITION
            GRAPHQL;
    }

    /**
     * Manipulate the AST based on a field definition.
     */
    public function manipulateFieldDefinition(
        DocumentAST &$documentAST,
        FieldDefinitionNode &$fieldDefinition,
        ObjectTypeDefinitionNode|InterfaceTypeDefinitionNode &$parentType
    ): void {
        if (!RootType::isRootType($parentType->name->value)) {
            throw new DefinitionException("Can not use @{$this->name()} on fields of a non-root type.");
        }
        if ($parentType->name->value !== 'Mutation') {
            throw new DefinitionException("@{$this->name()} may only be used on mutations, not queries.");
        }

        $returnType = $fieldDefinition->type;
        $mutationName = $fieldDefinition->name->value;
        $resultTypeName = $this->directiveArgValue('resultType', Str::studly($mutationName . 'Result'));

        // create a new type that wraps the original return type
        $resultType = new ObjectTypeDefinitionNode([
            'name' => new NameNode(['value' => $resultTypeName]),
            'description' => new StringValueNode(['value' => "A wrapped result for the '{$mutationName}' mutation."]),
            'interfaces' => new NodeList([]),
            'directives' => new NodeList([]),
            'fields' => new NodeList([
                new FieldDefinitionNode([
                    'name' => new NameNode(['value' => 'result']),
                    'type' => $returnType,
                    'arguments' => new NodeList([]),
                    'directives' => $fieldDefinition->directives,
                ]),
                new FieldDefinitionNode([
                    'name' => new NameNode(['value' => 'query']),
                    'type' => new NonNullTypeNode(['type' => new NamedTypeNode(['name' => new NameNode(['value' => 'Query'])])]),
                    'arguments' => new NodeList([]),
                    'directives' => new NodeList([]),
                ]),
            ]),
        ]);

        // register the new type with the AST
        $documentAST->setTypeDefinition($resultType);
        // replace the original return type with the new type
        $fieldDefinition->type = new NonNullTypeNode(['type' => new NamedTypeNode(['name' => new NameNode(['value' => $resultTypeName])])]);
    }

    /**
     * Wrap around the resolver of the field.
     */
    public function handleField(FieldValue $fieldValue): void
    {
        $fieldValue->resultHandler(function (mixed $result) {
            return [
                'result' => $result,
                'query' => [],
            ];
        });
    }
}

I've been trying to test this out with this schema:
extend type Mutation {
    setDiscountForLineItems(ids: ID!, discount: Float!): [OrderLineItem!]!
        @field(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\Controllers\\OrderLineItemController@setDiscountForLineItems")
        @exposeQuery
}

...and a resolver function that boils down to this:
class OrderLineItemController
{
    function setDiscountForLineItems($root, array $args): Collection
    {
        $ids = $args['ids'] ?? [];
        $discount = $args['discount'] ?? null;

        $builder = OrderLineItem::whereIn('id', $ids);
        $builder->update(['discount' => $discount]);

        return $builder->get();
    }
}

The schema compiles fine, as I would expect:
type Mutation {
  setDiscountForLineItems(ids: [ID!]!, discount: Float!): SetDiscountForLineItemsResult!
}

type SetDiscountForLineItemsResult {
  result: [OrderLineItem!]!
  query: Query!
}

However, when actually using it, I get an error:
{
    "extensions": {
        "debugMessage": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field \"OrderLineItem.id\".",
        "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
        "line": 853,
        "trace": [
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 753,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValue(GraphQLType: ID!, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(4), null, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 641,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValueCatchingError(GraphQLType: ID!, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(4), null, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 1317,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::resolveField(GraphQLType: OrderLineItem, array(1), instance of ArrayObject(1), array(4), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 1256,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeFields(GraphQLType: OrderLineItem, array(1), array(3), instance of ArrayObject(6), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 1211,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::collectAndExecuteSubfields(GraphQLType: OrderLineItem, instance of ArrayObject(1), array(3), array(1), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 893,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeObjectValue(GraphQLType: OrderLineItem, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(3), array(1), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 845,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValue(GraphQLType: OrderLineItem, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(3), array(1), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 753,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValue(GraphQLType: OrderLineItem!, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(3), array(1), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 985,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValueCatchingError(GraphQLType: OrderLineItem!, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(3), array(1), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 871,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeListValue(GraphQLType: [OrderLineItem!], instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(2), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 845,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValue(GraphQLType: [OrderLineItem!], instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(2), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 753,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValue(GraphQLType: [OrderLineItem!]!, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(2), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 641,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValueCatchingError(GraphQLType: [OrderLineItem!]!, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(2), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 1317,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::resolveField(GraphQLType: SetDiscountForLineItemsResult, array(2), instance of ArrayObject(1), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 1256,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeFields(GraphQLType: SetDiscountForLineItemsResult, array(2), array(1), instance of ArrayObject(3), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 1211,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::collectAndExecuteSubfields(GraphQLType: SetDiscountForLineItemsResult, instance of ArrayObject(1), array(1), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 893,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeObjectValue(GraphQLType: SetDiscountForLineItemsResult, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(1), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 845,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValue(GraphQLType: SetDiscountForLineItemsResult, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(1), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 753,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValue(GraphQLType: SetDiscountForLineItemsResult!, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(1), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 641,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::completeValueCatchingError(GraphQLType: SetDiscountForLineItemsResult!, instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, array(1), array(2), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 541,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::resolveField(GraphQLType: Mutation, null, instance of ArrayObject(1), array(1), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 949,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::GraphQL\\Executor\\{closure}(array(0), 'setDiscountForLineItems')"
            },
            {
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::GraphQL\\Executor\\{closure}(array(0), 'setDiscountForLineItems')"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 951,
                "function": "array_reduce(array(1), instance of Closure, array(0))"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 559,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::promiseReduce(array(1), instance of Closure, array(0))"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 297,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeFieldsSerially(GraphQLType: Mutation, null, array(0), instance of ArrayObject(1), instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                "line": 237,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeOperation(instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\OperationDefinitionNode, null)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/Executor.php",
                "line": 159,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::doExecute()"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/GraphQL.php",
                "line": 163,
                "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\Executor::promiseToExecute(instance of GraphQL\\Executor\\Promise\\Adapter\\SyncPromiseAdapter, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, null, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext, array(4), 'SetDiscountForLineItems', null)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/GraphQL.php",
                "line": 97,
                "call": "GraphQL\\GraphQL::promiseToExecute(instance of GraphQL\\Executor\\Promise\\Adapter\\SyncPromiseAdapter, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, null, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext, array(4), 'SetDiscountForLineItems', null, array(29))"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
                "line": 126,
                "call": "GraphQL\\GraphQL::executeQuery(instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, null, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext, array(4), 'SetDiscountForLineItems', null, array(29))"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
                "line": 86,
                "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL::executeParsedQuery(instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext, array(4), null, 'SetDiscountForLineItems')"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
                "line": 217,
                "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL::executeQueryString('mutation SetDiscountForLineItems($ids: [ID!]!, $discount_percent: Float!, $expiration_date: DateTime, $orderId: ID!) {\n  setDiscountForLineItems(\n    ids: $ids\n    discount_percent: $discount_percent\n    expiration_date: $expiration_date\n  ) {\n    query {\n      order(id: $orderId) {\n        id\n        totals {\n          id\n          orderTotal\n          itemsSubtotal\n          totalDiscountAmount\n          averageDiscountRate\n          salesTax\n          shippingSubtotal\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    result {\n      id\n      pricingModel {\n        id\n        regularSubtotal\n        discountPercent\n        overriddenSubtotal\n        discountAdjustmentAmount\n        discountUnitAdjustmentAmount\n        __typename\n      }\n      expiration_date\n      finalSubtotal\n      finalSubtotalUnrounded\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}', instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext, array(4), null, 'SetDiscountForLineItems')"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
                "line": 177,
                "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL::executeOperation(instance of GraphQL\\Server\\OperationParams, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Support/Utils.php",
                "line": 107,
                "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\{closure}(instance of GraphQL\\Server\\OperationParams)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
                "line": 177,
                "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Utils::mapEach(instance of Closure, instance of GraphQL\\Server\\OperationParams)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Http/GraphQLController.php",
                "line": 32,
                "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL::executeOperationOrOperations(instance of GraphQL\\Server\\OperationParams, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\HttpGraphQLContext)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
                "line": 46,
                "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Http\\GraphQLController::__invoke(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL, instance of Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher, instance of Laragraph\\Utils\\RequestParser, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\SingleResponse, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\ContextFactory)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
                "line": 260,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher::dispatch(instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Route, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Http\\GraphQLController, '__invoke')"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
                "line": 205,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route::runController()"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 806,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route::run()"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 141,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Http/Middleware/AcceptJson.php",
                "line": 24,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 180,
                "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Http\\Middleware\\AcceptJson::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 116,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 807,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 784,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::runRouteWithinStack(instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Route, instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 748,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::runRoute(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Route)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 737,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::dispatchToRoute(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
                "line": 200,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::dispatch(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 141,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
                "line": 21,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
                "line": 31,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 180,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
                "line": 21,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
                "line": 40,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 180,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
                "line": 27,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 180,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
                "line": 99,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 180,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php",
                "line": 62,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 180,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 116,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
                "line": 175,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
                "line": 144,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::sendRequestThroughRouter(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/backend/public/index.php",
                "line": 67,
                "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
            }
        ]
    }
}

When I manually specify the SetDiscountForLineItemsResult in my schema, change the return type of the field, and modify the resolver to return ['result' => $builder->get()] and test it with the exact same dataset, it works exactly as expected, so something is going wrong in the directive, I'm just not sure what.

something ins't right the OrderLineItem.id is getting null and because you have the ! it can't allow
